# "Make easy" vs. "make it easy"

Tags: grammaticality, dummy-it

I need to know which of these options is the correct one and why:

> - The Spanish cooking makes it easy to have a nice meal.
> - The Spanish cooking makes easy to have a nice meal.

I don't know if I need the pronoun *it* or not. By the way, is "a nice meal" correct, or should I use any other adjective, such as "good"?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: This is probably a question for [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). However, ask yourself the question "What does Spanish cooking make easy?" The phrase "Spanish cooking makes..." requires an **object**, which is what is supplied by the dummy *it*. [*It* is normally a dummy subject, but here that pronoun fulfils a similar function as an object.] It's also not "The Spanish cooking", but just "Spanish cooking", which is another matter which I'm sure has been mentioned here in a prior question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know about ELL. It's my first time here and I'm a bit lost. Thank you!

Comment: ELL probably won't help you much. Beside the article problem, the presence or absence of _it_ is a tricky grammatical point, since it could be one of several different kinds. This one is the dummy _it_ of Extraposition, and it's almost all that's left of a subordinate clause.

Comment: Do you mean the *methods* of Spanish cooking?  Otherwise, I'm confused before you get to the "makes easy"/"makes it easy" part.

Comment: Yes, I actually mean those _methods_. Maybe "cooking" is not the most appropriate word, is it? I'm not sure at all...

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct. "Makes" is the verb, "it" is the object of which "makes" refers to, and "easy" is the adjective. "It" refers to the work done to prepare the meal. However, referring to the work in general is informal English and can be improved by expanding upon the aspect of work that has been made easy. The word "nice" is much more professional than the word "good." "Good" implies that the meal would not be appetizing if it were not for the Spanish cooking. However, the word "nice" implies that the meal is enjoyable to eat in general because of the Spanish cooking.

The phrase, "Make easy" is an expression used to mean, "to get along with again," or, "to resolve." When people say, "Let's make easy," it is usually after a conflict between two closely related people and is said by an outside party.

Answer (score 0):

Neither sentence is correct.

> Spanish cooking makes it easy to have a nice meal. [This is grammatical and natural]
>   Spanish cooking makes having a nice meal easy. [This is grammatical and natural]

You can use any adjective that suits your fancy instead of the [tepid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tepid) *nice*.

Comment: Brits might often say "a *good* meal".

Comment: @TrevorD: That's less tepid. I'd say "tasty & inexpensive". Those are my two top criteria.

Comment: Actually, although I agree that *nice* can be tepid, it's not always so. Here (in S.England), a guest saying *That was a **(very) nice** meal. Thank you* (with the emphasis on *nice*) would a fairly normal expression with no adverse or 'tepid' connotations.

Comment: @TrevorD: Same in the USA, but _nice_ is just so faux-vanilla bland that it's beyond the pale of simple cliché: it's mummified when it's not necrotic.